# What is the max number of fields that can be declared/used in a TFS Collection?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem, tfs-process-template

I'm using TFS 2017 update 1 on premises. I have planned so many new fields to be declared/used in my custom process template for future developments (domani fields, custom advanced history fields, etc.). I'm afraid that at some point I'll discover that is not possible to declare/use further new fields. Hence what exactly is the max number of fields that can be declared/used in a TFS Collection?

I ask that because I found this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/settings/work/object-limits?view=vsts, then I trivially tried to declare more than 512 fields in a same workitem type (all fields are only for test scope like field1, field2, ..., field512, etc.). It seems that TFS allows to declare and use more than 512 fields, so what is the effective limit? Why the limit is not 512 as documented in above link?

Comment: The link speaks about VSTS, not about TFS on-premise.

Comment: Is there any documentation specific of TFS on-premise?

Comment: See Andy's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The on-premise TFS limits is documented here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/work-item-field?view=vsts#what-is-a-field-how-are-field-names-used

> When adding custom fields, note the following limits:
>
> - A maximum of 256 fields can be defined for each WIT
> - A maximum of 512 fields can be defined per process

However if you can add customized fields more than 256 for each WIT, then it should be an document issue...